# Calling .Net built-in classes from win32 dll

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, encryption

I'm stuck in working on a win32 dll (Source in C++) which i need triple des decryption.

Client wants to use those classes in the .Net System.Security.Cryptography namespace as the encrypted data is prepared by another .net program.

Is there any (easy) way to achieve this?

I have suggested to use crypto api but client says it is incompatible. Sometimes decrypted text with strange trailing characters...

Comment: It's not a question of .Net versus crypto API, it's a matter of algorithms and protocols. These are platform-independent and it doesn't matter whether they're implemented in .NET or unmanaged crypto api.

Comment: Your client has it completely wrong. Triple DES is a standard. There are countless compatible implementations. Be firm with your client. If your client is not competent enough to decrypt then that is a problem at their end, and not with the underlying algo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual way to do it is to use managed C++ to bridge between C++ and C# worlds.

An alternative could be to make [a COM-friendly managed DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736).

Comment: I understand, but that win32 dll is to be loaded in TCL runtime, which cannot be managed C++ (actually i'm not quite sure)

Comment: @Johnny It's not cool to supply all the project constraints in comments after people have taken the time to answer. If you don't put it in the question, then it doesn't exist. What's in your head, and not written down, does not exist to us.

Comment: @Johnny An alternative could be to make a COM-friendly managed DLL. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736.

Comment: @AlexD Thanks Alex, the link gives me the answer.

Comment: @Johnny Great :). I just updated my answer accordingly. (Still, it could make sense to discuss with your customer if .NET is really needed in this case.)